# javascript not working on main content or head content

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

when i am using javascript code in that format like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetButtonStatus(sender, target) {
        var first = document.getElementById('<%=txtfirst.ClientID %>');
        var second = document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID %>');
        //Condition to check whether user enters text in two textboxes or not
        if ((sender.value.length >= 1 && first.value.length >= 1) && (sender.value.length >= 1 && second.value.length >= 1))
            document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirst" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

its runnung perfect and javascript work fine,

but when i am using this javascript code in another page like

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetButtonStatus(sender, target) {
        var first = document.getElementById('<%=txtfirst.ClientID %>');
        var second = document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID %>');
        //Condition to check whether user enters text in two textboxes or not
        if ((sender.value.length >= 1 && first.value.length >= 1) && (sender.value.length >= 1 && second.value.length >= 1))
            document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirst" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server"  onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false"/>
</asp:Content>
```

javascript not working and no error issue.

i am using visual studio 2010
asp.net c#.

Comment: @mplungjan how to do that

Comment: Is this JavaScript passed to the browser? What is the HTML that is sent to the browser?

Comment: Right click in the browser, click view source or hit F12 and look in the sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass actual ID of button you get after rendering the page. (you can copy from view source)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirst" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
```

it will work.

Thanks

Comment: how to null 2 or more TextBox using only one "txtfirst"

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirst" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this,'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnButton')"></asp:TextBox> how to target more textbox using this code.